# Type mismatch on create element sails-dynamodb

Tags: javascript, sails.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using this module and when I tried to create an Object Sails send me back ("Type mismatch for attribute to update")

This is my code:

Model:

```
module.exports = {
 attributes: {
  id:{
  type: 'string',
  primaryKey: 'range'
 },
 picture:{
  type: "string",
  required: true
 },
 title:{
  type: "string",
  required: true
 },
 subcategories:{
  collection: 'Subcategory',
  via: 'category_ref'
 },
 user_ref:{
  model: 'User'
 }
}
};
```

Controller:

```
create: function (req, res, next) {
       let  name = "sometext";
        var obj = {
            id: new String(uuidv4()),
            picture: name,
            title: req.param('title')
        }
        Category.create(obj, function (err, cat) {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                return res.send(cat);
            }
        });
    });
},
```

I verified with an `instanceof` and it's an String.

My Sails version is 0.12.14.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is you are using `new String(uuidv4())`. When you use `new` with the primitive constructors like String, Number, or Boolean, the constructor returns an Object. This isn't what you want. Instead, drop the `new` and just call the constructor like any ordinary function, e.g. `String(uuidv4())`. When called in this way, the constructor returns a primitive.

The following examples should give you an idea of the difference

```
> new String('test') instanceof String
true
> typeof new String('test')
'object'
> String('test') instanceof String
false
> typeof String('test')
'string'
> new String('test') === 'test'
false
> String('test') === 'test'
true
```

There are a few other things that stand out. `id` is defined as the range key on your model and there isn't a hash key of your model. Also, `req.param('title')` might be returning undefined, null, or something that is not a string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply by that don't solve the problem, I tried all of them. Regards

Comment: Updated with a couple other ideas

Comment: I cast `req.param('title')` to a string and that solve the problem, just like you said. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also I needed to delete old local database after model changes.